# How to apply pagination in dojo

Tags: dojo, pagination

Is there a type of pagination that allows the user to enter the page number available which is not similar to the goto button in the Dojo pagination?

Here's an example of what I mean:

[image]

In this example, there is a text box in which the user can specify the page number and afterwards he is taken to the respective page.

Can this be done? If so, can u please help me with this ... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Everything is possible with JavaScript, and also with Dojo. However, there is no standard component, there is a third party pagination component (https://github.com/driskull/dijit-pagination-js) but that does not fit your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

script.js

```
  function paginate(){

    //create pagination buttons

    if(data.length  >= 5){
        for(var y = 0; y < data.length / 5 ; y++) { // divide by 5 to get results per page equal to 5
            var button = document.createElement("button");
            button.setAttribute("id", "pagination-button" + (y+1).toString());
            button.setAttribute("class", "pagination-button center");
            button.setAttribute("onclick", "nav(id)");
            var text = document.createTextNode((y + 1).toString());
            button.appendChild(text);
            document.body.appendChild(button);
        }
    }
}
function removeChildNodes() {
    document.getElementById("searchResults").innerHTML = "";
}
function nav(id){
    removeChildNodes()
    showPages(document.getElementById(id).innerHTML);
}
function showPages (pageNum) {
    //get upperbound reults
    pageNum = parseInt(pageNum);
    var upperBoundResults = (pageNum * 5); // gets increments of 5 per page if page 1 , 5 results
    //get lower bound results to start at 
    var lowerBoundResults = (upperBoundResults - 5); // if page 2, lower bound is 5 upper 10
    for(lowerBoundResults; lowerBoundResults<upperBoundResults; lowerBoundResults++) {
        if(data[lowerBoundResults]) {
             document.getElementById("searchResults").innerHTML += "<div class='center'>" +
             "Name: "   + data[lowerBoundResults].title      + "</div>"; 
            } else {
                break; // breaks if no longer any results that would throw an error
            }
        }
}

showPages(1);
paginate();

index.html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="searchResults"></div>

    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </html>
```

What this does is make a paginate button every 5 entries. So, create you JSON object in data, and it should be good to go.

Comment: Can you help me with a code which uses dojo in wcs??? so that gotopage text box can be enabled??

Comment: Just turn document.getelementbyid to $, dojo doesn't really do much. Why does it have to be in Dojo, vanilla JS is compatible with everything.